# Is this code undefined behaviour?

Tags: c

I have a variable i:

```
int i;
if(b){
    i=1;
}
else{
    i=-1;
}
```

Is `i` undefined behavior because of `int i;` exists?
Or Should we always `int i=0` first?

Comment: This is perfectly defined behavior (except for the missing semicolons) : you do not "use" `i` before any assignment to it. After your if/else, `i` will have a defined value (either `1` or `-1`)

Comment: Added the statement terminator on the first line and in the `else` block as this question is not really about typos. Roll back if not to taste.

Comment: What is `b` and has it been initialised? If the latter is not the case, the code invokes UB.

Comment: That code won't compile as `｛ != {`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely fine.

You are initialising `i` on all program control paths, and not reading the value until initialisation is complete.

I prefer using the ternary operator in such instances.

`int i = b ? 1 : -1;`

as that's less vulnerable to accidental reference to an uninitialised `i`.

Comment: However, it is not obvious to everyone that `?:` sits just 1 notch above `=` in the operator precedence. To avoid misunderstandings, I would either have written `int i = ( b!=0 ? 1 : -1 );` or kept the original code, which was more readable.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed, although I subscribe to the perhaps old-fashioned view that you should commit your operator precedence table to memory at a very young age and *never* use excess parentheses. In fact, excess parentheses is an indication that something funky is happening. I seem to recall that the numerical recipes professors recommend your sticking a copy on your lavatory door. Personally I think ternary should sit just above the short-circutted AND and OR, but that's another matter.

Comment: Certainly a C veteran knows the operator precedence, but in cases where it isn't obvious to the average programmer, parenthesis are helpful (particularly when communicating with beginners on SO). Take the classic bug `if(x & 1 == 0)` as one example of where things go wrong when people who are too confident of their operator precedence knowledge go trip themselves. I've found that bug in production code so many times... code which was supposedly not written by beginners.

Comment: I fully agree with your statement regarding excessive use of parenthesis though, it is indeed often a certain sign that the programmer who wrote the code wasn't quite sure what their own program was doing... which is never a good sign. One typical example: `return (0);`

Answer (score 3):

It is just like saying

```
int i;
i=1;  // or -1 for that matter
```

How can that be undefined? it's not. If you were to read `i` before assigning a value to it then yes it would be undefined.

> Or Should we always int i=0 first?

There is no such compulsion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code which you haven't seen. Please add the semicolon after `i=-1` which will become `i=-1;` because there is no semicolon after i=-1 that's why it is displaying the error message

Comment: Sorry, have invalidated this, but it was more of a comment anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `int i;` without any intializations, a memory address of size `int` is reserved for your variable, this address could contain any possible value. 
for example if you output the variable, any number could be seen

```
int i;
printf( "i = %d", i);    // i will equel any value of (int)
```

you can always define the variable and intialize it later

```
int i;
printf( "i = %d", i);    // i will equel any value of (int)
i = 5;
printf( "i = %d", i);    // i = 5
```